# Abelian scheme isogenous to dual

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, abelian-schemes

It is well-known that every Abelian *variety* is isogenous to its dual, but what about Abelian *schemes*?

Comment: It seems likely that an abelian scheme which is projective is isogenous to its dual: the construction of the dual abelian variety as a quotient (as in Mumford's book) probably extends to this setting.

Comment: @ulrich: yes, given a relatively ample line bundle $L$, we can make the map $\phi_L: A \rightarrow \widehat{A}$ by the same functorial recipe as in Mumford's book, and it is an isogeny by the theory on geometric fibers. That the dual abelian scheme exists in general (without projectivity hypotheses) is a hard result proceeding through algebraic spaces. See Ch. XII of Raynaud's thesis (SLN 119) for abelian schemes not projective locally on the base.

Comment: When does a relatively ample line bundle exist, and what is a reference for this?

Comment: @TimoKeller: a relatively ample exists when the base is noetherian and normal. See Raynaud's thesis,(SLN 119), Théorème XI.1.13 on p. 170. Condition (A) used there is defined in XI.1.2, p. 159.

Comment: Why don't you make your comments into an answer?